# Creatures known for excessive planning - demonic or evil favored

Tags: myth-identification, mythical-creatures, ghosts, demons

I'm looking for creatures that are mostly known for either acting very carefully planned or for providing well thought out plans to others. Specifically creatures that are demonic or otherwise of a more evil/dark tone.

Comment: This is not a demon but an Egyptian god, known for arbitrating disputes and helping gods in general https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoth . Another starting point could be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knowledge_deities
I am not familiar with any demons but hope this is helpful anyway.

Comment: Did you come upon the [Moirai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moirai) and their [Theoi page](https://www.theoi.com/Daimon/Moirai.html), they are also known as the Fates in the Greek mythology and have the Parcae as equivalent in the roman one. They are not demons by themselves but their ascendance often refers to dark (not necessarily evil in any point) and mysterious deities. "They controlled the mother thread of life of every mortal from birth to death." suits well what you want

Comment: "Scheming" is an adjective very commonly associated with Zeus, although he is a "sky father".  However, Prometheus' name means "forethought", which connotes strategy, and he tricks Zeus more than once.  (Prometheus is one of the templates for the fallen angels--would he qualify?)